Stuck with a binary file that contains a file, how to get access back to it?
I used the mv command (sudo mv 7_00.tts ~/Desktop) in Linux Terminal to move a file to a specific folder. The destination folder didnt exist unfortunatly. Now i have a file (type:binary) that is named like the destination folder and it includes the file that i need (The size of the binary file shows it contains the moved file). I dont have the original file (a video file) anymore so its only in the binary file. Is there a way to get the file back that i moved?
I tried to just rename the file to the original file type, but due to the folder in between its obviously not working. Didnt try anything else due to lack of knowledge.

I you ran exactly mv 7_00.tts ~/Desktop and the target dir didn't exist ("Desktop"? It should normally exist?) your file should be found in your home directory and named Desktop, in that case it would be a matter of running mv ~/Desktop 7_00.ts. Did you instead run mv 7_00.tts ~Desktop? In that case, mv '~Desktop' 7_00.ts  would suffice. What is reporting the file as being binary? If neither of these commands help, please post the output of ls -la ~

@kos my os is in german, so its "Schreibtisch" not Desktop. On Windows in EN and GER its both "Desktop", thats why the mistake happend.

Ah got it, yes, I too have to switch between Italian and English sometimes, I can definetly see the mistake happening :)

I assume the 'Desktop' file is actually your new file.
So in essence you just moved your original file and renamed it as 'Desktop'. Remember, in linux based os, extension which comes at the end of the filename hardly matters. So even if say, you have a text file 'abc.txt' and you rename it to 'abc', it will still be a text file and would not have become a binary.
You only have to
mv ~/Desktop 7_00.tts
See if you get your original file back.

By definition, any file that contains non-printable characters (and in particular characters below 0x20) is binary. So if the original file was a video file, it was already binary :)

@raj Yeah that is! Should have been more precise. I mentioned text file, so.

This "binary" file is your original file, only you renamed it.
You should rename it back to the original name.
If you ran the command sudo mv 7_00.tts ~/Desktop (I don't understand why you used sudo, it shouldn't be normally needed to move/rename files within your home directory), then run the opposite: sudo mv ~/Desktop 7_00.tts.

I used Sudo, because i copied the data from a HDD that only allowed root to copy files. Thanks for your help!
